# ¿Por qué mi aplicación hecha en React me da error 404 en todas las páginas salvo la principal?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, reactjs

Estoy intentando probar la versión de producción de una web que he hecho utilizando React, pero cuando ejecuto serve -s build y abro mi web, todas las páginas menos la principal me lanzan un error 404.

En el archivo Index.js envuelvo la llamada a App.js utilizando BrowserRouter:

```
  <BrowserRouter>
    <App />
  </BrowserRouter>,
```

Y la navegación está definida en el archivo App.js utilizando react-router-dom. Se ve así:

```
  <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
  <Route path="/ilustraciones" component={Ilustraciones} />
  <Route path="/galeria" component={Galeria} />
  <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
  <Route path="/visor" component={Loginvisor} />
  <Route path="/visorstl" component={LoginvisorSTL} />
  <Route path="/profile" component={Profile} />
  <Route path="/DICOM" component={LoginVisorDICOM} />
```

Mi web, si es necesario mirar en otro lado, está aquí: https://github.com/rgomez96/Tecnolab (en la rama Develop)

¿Cómo puedo solucionar esto? No es mandatorio desplegar la web utilizando serve así que podría cambiarlo si fuera necesario.

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y, de paso, ganar tu primera medalla. También es importante que leas [ask] y [mcve] para poder mejorar tus preguntas y que sean bien recibidas por la comunidad, de esta manera favoreces a que los usuarios las respondan y te ayuden

Comment: Basicamente le tienes que decir a tu servidor web que todas las urls que sean solicitadas se envie el index.html para asi poder montar la aplicacion y el javascript tomar el control sobre las rutas. ¿ Que servidor utilizas(nginx, apache)?

Comment: Al dar error al ejecutar serve no he intentado utilizar ningún servidor todavía, pero en principio tengo la intención de usar Nginx.

Comment: [Aqui](https://medium.com/socratescl/configuracion-nginx-reactjs-317ae0553174) te explican el problema que tienes.

Answer (score 1):

Lo que pasa es que te falta algo con que cambiar de componente de acuerdo a la ruta, lo que te falta es un Switch, Un Switch mira a través de sus hijos Routes y renderiza el primero que coincide con la URL actual...Ya despues de agregado entonces quedaria algo asi:

```
<Switch>
    <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
      <Route path="/ilustraciones" component={Ilustraciones} />
      <Route path="/galeria" component={Galeria} />
      <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
      <Route path="/visor" component={Loginvisor} />
      <Route path="/visorstl" component={LoginvisorSTL} />
      <Route path="/profile" component={Profile} />
      <Route path="/DICOM" component={LoginVisorDICOM} />
</Switch>
```

Answer (score 0):

Probablemente el servidor que sirve el build no tiene configurado el `fallback`. Esto lo que hace es que si una ruta `/ejemplo` no coincide con un archivo la petición se redirige al index.html.

Esto es necesario en las aplicaciones SPA sino dará error 404 en todas las rutas como te esta pasando.

Yo he utilizado este [servidor](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server-spa) para solucionar este problema pero existen más por ahi, encuentra en el que mejor te vaya o configura el fallback en el que ya usas si lo permite.